# SQL Subtract two different averages in one single coulmn

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database for the airport.
I have one table named "employees" and one other table named "certified".
The "employees" table includes the names of all employees(pilot and other employees) and the staff code
named "eid" and the number of their salaries.
[image]

The certified table contains the pilot staff who specify which aircrafts they can fly.
[image]

**WHAT I WANT:** I want to subtract the average salary of pilots and the average salary of all employees(pilot and other employees).

I use this code:

```
Select AVG(salary) - (Select AVG(salary) from employees) as subtract
from employees as e,
     certified as c
where e.eid = c.eid
```

**but I have a problem :**
As you can see in the "certified" table the "eid" of some pilots is repeated and affects the average value.

**How can I use a salary only once in the calculation?**

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please specify **one** DBMS.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: I'm using sql @jarlh

Comment: SQL is a language, supported by many products - many with own extensions and restrictions.

Comment: ok, I'm using MySQL  @jarlh

Comment: Then you can remove the <ms-access> tag.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like below using [SWITCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) statement in MS Access

```
select 
AVG(salary) - AVG( switch(IsPilot =1,salary,IsPilot=0,NULL)) as substract
from 
(
select 
 distinct 
    e.eid, 
    e.salary, 
    Switch( c.eid is not null, 1 ,c.eid is NULL, 0) as IsPilot 
from 
employees e left join certified c
  on e.id=c.eid )T
```

corresponding statement in MySql is

```
select 
AVG(salary) - AVG( case when IsPilot =1 then salary when IsPilot=0 then NULL end)  as substract
from 
(
select 
 distinct 
    e.eid, 
    e.salary, 
    case when c.eid is not null then  1  when c.eid is NULL then 0 as IsPilot 
from 
employees e left join certified c
  on e.id=c.eid )T
```

Comment: For MS Access I'd prefer to use `IIF()`... it is both shorter and faster, and (it seems) more clear than `switch()`. PS. I do not see the reason for to convert `c.eid` twice, to `IsPilot` then to `salary/null` - you may transfer it into outer query as-is.

Comment: @Akina the inner query is like CTE to show what and how we solve problem 1 i.e. distinguishing pilots vs other staff. Problem 2 is to calculate difference between averages of salary. Tomorrow OP may need something else like say difference between avg salary of pilot vs non pilot then OP will be able to follow flow and fish the solution by self.

Comment: I understand your queries logic carefully. That's why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(e.salary) - AVG(CASE WHEN c.eid IS NOT NULL THEN e.salary END) as difference
FROM employees AS e
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT eid
            FROM certified ) AS c ON e.eid=c.eid
```

First AVG calculates average salary over all rows, second - only for those rows (those employees) which have matched row(s) in `certified` table (all another rows have NULL for inner CASE, so they are not counted).

The query assumes that `eid` column is unique (maybe, primary key) in `employees` table.

PS. Maybe AVGs in the substraction must be swapped...

---

In MS Access this code may be

```
SELECT AVG(e.salary) - AVG(IIF(c.eid IS NOT NULL, e.salary, NULL)) as difference
FROM employees AS e
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT eid
            FROM certified ) AS c ON e.eid=c.eid
```

Comment: @MahdiAspanani SQL is a language. So the code cannot be "for" SQL, it is for MySQL and is written on SQL. Access-specific code added.